# No identifier specified for entity Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing sample program in Spring boot with Hibernate . I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.demo.model.CheckRes
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.demo.model.CheckRes
...
```

I have specified identity column as well.

**CheckRepository.java**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.CheckRes;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CheckRepository extends JpaRepository<CheckRes,Long> {
}
```

What else is missing in Model according to the error?

Edit1:
I added the getter and setter to the model but still the same error:

```
package com.example.demo.model;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="CheckRes")
public class CheckRes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ID;

    @Column(name="Check")
    private String Check;

    public CheckRes() {
    }

    public CheckRes(String check) {
        Check = check;
    }

    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getCheck() {
        return Check;
    }

    public void setCheck(String check) {
        Check = check;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an id but it is private and cannot be accessed by any other class. Just create a getter method for your id.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after changing

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

to

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```